# Display of dictionary in django

Tags: python, django, dictionary

My List

```
book_details = [
    {'author':'abc', 'book_name':'xyz', 's_no':1},
    {'author':'efg', 'book_name':'ijk', 's_no':2}
]
```

My code:

```
{% for dict in details %}
    <tr>
        {% for key, value in dict.items %}
            <td>{{ value }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>               
{% endfor %}
```

Output :

```
Author   Book_name  S_no
```

Desired output:

```
S_no  Book_name Author
```

I'm new to django , please guide.

Comment: Explain what? Dictionaries are unordered, and this has nothing to do with Django.

Comment: Possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/python-dictionary-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared

Comment: @DanielRoseman He's using Django template structures, but that's about it

Comment: Dictionaries do not maintain order. You may try for ordereddicts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% for dict in details %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{dict.s_no}}</td>
                    <td>{{dict.book_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{dict.author}}</td>

                </tr>

{% endfor%}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are iterating through each key-value pair in the dictionary, so your code is outputting dictionary values in the order in which they are stored in the dictionary, which happens to be:

```
Author Book_name S_no
```

So, you have two options.

1. **Change the order in which these attributes are stored in the dictionary.** If you change the structure of your dictionaries from `{'author': 'abc', 'book_name':'xyz','s_no':1}` to `{'s_no':1, 'book_name':'xyz', 'author': 'abc'}`, iterating over the key-value pairs will return these attributes in the desired order. However, this is not a very flexible solution, so I would suggest the second option.
2. **Change the way you output dictionary values.** Instead of iterating through all the key-value pairs in whatever order they happen to be in, you can explicitly define the order in which you want to output dictionary values by changing this:

   ```
   {% for key,value in dict.items %}
   <td>{{value}}</td>
   {% endfor %}
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   {% for key in ['S_no', 'Book_name', 'Author'] %}
   <td>{{dict[key]}}</td>
   {% end for %}
   ```

   This solution has the added benefit of being quite easy to modify if, later on, you decide you want to output these values in another order.

Comment: I tried your method, I'm getting this error. Could not parse the remainder: '['s_no','book_name','author']' from '['s_no','book_name','author']'

Comment: {% for dict in details %} 
    <tr>
         <td>{{dict.s_no}}</td>
         <td>{{dict.book_name}}</td>
         <td>{{dict.author}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
This worked for me.